# Is it possible or make sense to create a jquery / .NET Service only web site?

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, web-services, soa

What I mean is since the direction seems to be toward doing more on the client... Why not just have a web site that is just jquery/HTML on the front end and nothing but .NET web services on the back end that are called by the jquery ajax commands?

Is this done anywhere? I don't see it being done .. how come? Seems like a simple solution. No need to deal with a ASP.NET abstraction layer..

Comment: Perhaps because that doesn't adhere to "graceful degradation" and "progressive enhancement" - if a user has JS disabled, the site is 100% unusable.

Comment: Not having JS enabled is like running Windows 3.1.  Of course nothing new and exciting will work :)  The people with the money to spend are all using JavaScript-enabled browsers.

Comment: I forgot about JS. I am hoping in 2011 you can require people to have a browser that uses it

Comment: It seems to me the ultimate way to divide developers and designers isnt it? no more have to deal with the whole page state concept.. let the javascript people deal with it

Comment: See also responses to [my question on webmasters.stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/advantages-disadvantages-of-separated-web-applications) for more points of view.

Comment: @jmort253:  Selectively running JS is like leaving your anti-virus on, and some people who have money do it.  There should be at least a static HTML page showing what you're missing by not enabling JS.

Comment: I read that post. Seems like there was no one saying it CANT be done.. its just nobody has done it with .net. Its like the MVVM concept in Silverlight the HTML page is a view and the web services area viewmodel and they don't need to know about each other

Comment: btw, its purely curiostity on mypart.. I am not writing any application at the moment with this in mind. I justam wondering why it is never done why it seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: @David Thomley - Do you run without JavaScript?  Just curious.  I have never actually met anyone with a setup like that.  I understand the concept behind people turning it off, but it seems like they are the minority, ans trying to support them in my opinion holds the rest of us back.  It would  be cool if there was some kind of way to selectively turn off only certain features of JavaScript instead of the entire engine.

Comment: How much to depend on Javascript depends a lot on your goals. And in practice the number of people who have it off is probably very small.

Answer (score 3):

Google has a demo that demonstrates this methodology you're referring to.  It's the [Autoshoppe Demo](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/demos/autoshoppe/README?spec=svn46&r=46) for Google App Engine.  Although it's Java, the concepts also apply to .NET applications.

The app contains plain vanilla HTML pages with .html extensions.  There is no server side view technologies to complicate an HTML programmer's life.  The HTML pages use JavaScript AJAX to interact with REST Web Services built using Spring 3.0, which interact with a datastore.

- The request data is passed as JSON in the request
- The response data is returned as JSON in the response.

What this means is that anyone can build a user interface on top of this API, or you could create a .NET project that interacts with that data.  REST is a great architecture for creating extensible, layered services.

I think the reason this technique is not widely used is because many people are stuck on view technologies that encourage developers to use the view technology vendor's markup in the HTML, such as ASP files (or JSP for Java).  It's a practice that has been around for awhile because fundamentally the writers of these frameworks are engineers, not web designers and UI designers.

It also takes a fairly strong understanding of REST to see the advantages this method offers, and junior developers sometimes struggle with these concepts.

If you were to tackle this in .NET, using the AutoShoppe demo as a guideline, you would most likely want to use an object mapper that can convert your JSON to a .NET object and back to JSON.  This is a much cleaner approach than trying to parse JSON yourself.

The advantages of this RESTful approach is that your content, behavior, and presentation are completely, 100% separate to the point where you could give your web programmer the HTML files and he/she could run them completely outside of the .NET environment.  Your designers can then use **their tools** and focus on their strengths, not ever having to install, configure, or run Visual Studio.NET.  In fact, the files would run right from the desktop.

**EDIT**: Perhaps a disadvantage is that there isn't much support for this in many MVC frameworks, mostly because it's a new concept.  The bridge between the client side and the server side currently must be written by the developer.

In the AutoShoppe demo, the developers wrote a prototype class in JavaScript to handle converting data into JSON before sending to the server, and they had to write JavaScript code to marshall the JSON into JavaScript objects and manipulate that data back into HTML.  On the server side, they did use an Object Mapper to deserialize the JSON to objects.  Most of the complexity was on the server.

The advantages of turning the server side component into a 100% reusable RESTful service that designers and clients can easily interact with may outweight the disadvantages, depending on the scenario.  A good example may be for a service where your clients are encouraged to code their own user interfaces or have full control over product whitelabeling.  This is one of many reasons  [why I won't use server side view technologies](http://blog.opensourceopportunities.com/2010/12/facts-web-design-and-web-development.html).

Comment: so why REST web services in stead of normal soap web services?  I assume the hardest part would be doing the client side templates and having to do in jquery what was done automatically for you with viewstate maybe? Strange that there are new .NET proof of concepts of this given the extremely nice seperation of concerns.

Comment: And where does .NET MVC fit into this? There is no webform concept.. but rather than call a web service to then populate the HTML on the client side it reloads the entire HTML from the server side

Comment: @punkouter - REST is more flexible and much simpler than SOAP.  REST can support a complex layered system or a simple service accessible through just a URL.  One disadvantage is there currently isn't a simple way to handle automatic views.  I'll update my answer to reflect.  For webforms, you would use AJAX to POST the request and use the callback method to update the form fields.  No need to do a full refresh, which makes the web page a richer Internet application.

Comment: What do you mean by automatic views?

Comment: @punkouter - Sorry, I was referring to your comment about using the viewstate to do things automatically.  I don't believe there is a framework to handle the REST website concept automatically like you can with server-side views.

Answer (score 0):

Its is quite possible. I have a site that once the initial page loads the server only sends JSON data which is rendered on the client. (though the server in this case runs php)

Comment: So it sounds like this concept has been done in everything but .NET.  It is really that hard I wonder? I must be missing some big reason why no one has done this.

Comment: no idea, I'm sure someone has, its just I don't know about it. Thats the nice thing about having a protocall. Both sides agree to send JSON over HTTP and what languages each side uses is flexable